# MFC application assert in dialog using vc++ 2008 on XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

In this line

```
GetDlgItem(ID_edit1)->SetWindowText("text1");
```

In debug mode in a XP PC, the program crashes. It works In release mode. Also, on a win 7 PC, it won't crash in either the debug or release modes.

The error message I'm getting:

```
debug assert failed!  ... vsprintf.c
the Buffer is too small!
```

What puzzles me is why some other similar edit boxes work. Variables are of type `CEdit`.

Comment: do this CWnd* dlgItem = GetDlgItem(ID_edit1) and check whether dlgItem is valid

Comment: Check your resources.h file and ensure there are no duplicates for the number corresponding to `ID_edit1`.